# Clarifications needed for concurrent operations, NSOperationQueue and async APIs

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

This is a two part question. Hope someone could reply with a complete answer.

`NSOperation`s are powerful objects. They can be of two different types: non-concurrent or concurrent.

The first type runs synchronously. You can take advantage of a non-concurrent operations by adding them into a `NSOperationQueue`. The latter creates a thread(s) for you. The result consists in running that operation in a concurrent manner. The only caveat regards the lifecycle of such an operation. When its `main` method finishes, then it is removed form the queue. This is can be a problem when you deal with async APIs.

Now, what about concurrent operations? From Apple doc

> If you want to implement a concurrent operation—that is, one that runs
>   asynchronously with respect to the calling thread—you must write
>   additional code to start the operation asynchronously. For example,
>   you might spawn a separate thread, call an asynchronous system
>   function, or do anything else to ensure that the start method starts
>   the task and returns immediately and, in all likelihood, before the
>   task is finished.

This is quite almost clear to me. They run asynchronously. But you must take the appropriate actions to ensure that they do.

What it is not clear to me is the following. Doc says:

> Note: In OS X v10.6, operation queues ignore the value returned by
>   isConcurrent and always call the start method of your operation from a
>   separate thread.

What it really means? **What happens if I add a concurrent operation in a `NSOperationQueue`?**

Then, in this post [Concurrent Operations](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/), concurrent operations are used to download some HTTP content by means of `NSURLConnection` (in its async form). Operations are concurrent and included in a specific queue.

```
UrlDownloaderOperation * operation = [UrlDownloaderOperation urlDownloaderWithUrlString:url];
[_queue addOperation:operation];
```

Since `NSURLConnection` requires a loop to run, the author shunt the `start` method in the main thread (so I suppose adding the operation to the queue it has spawn a different one). In this manner, the main run loop can invoke the delegate included in the operation.

```
- (void)start
{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_url];
    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                  delegate:self];
    if (_connection == nil)
        [self finish];
}

- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
    return YES;
}

// delegate method here...
```

My question is the following. **Is this thread safe?** The run loop listens for sources but invoked methods are called in a background thread. Am I wrong?

**Edit**

I've completed some tests on my own based on the code provided by Dave Dribin (see [1](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/)). I've noticed, as you wrote, that callbacks of `NSURLConnection` are called in the **main thread**.

Ok, but now I'm still very confusing. I'll try to explain my doubts.

Why including within a **concurrent** operation an async pattern where its callback are called in the main thread? Shunting the `start` method to the main thread it allows to execute callbacks in the main thread, and what about queues and operations? Where do I take advantage of threading mechanisms provided by GCD?

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is kind of a long answer, but the short version is that what you're doing is totally fine and thread safe since you've forced the important part of the operation to run on the main thread.

Your first question was, "What happens if I add a concurrent operation in a NSOperationQueue?" [As of iOS 4](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1712/_index.html), `NSOperationQueue` uses GCD behind the scenes. When your operation reaches the top of the queue, it gets submitted to GCD, which manages a pool of private threads that grows and shrinks dynamically as needed. GCD assigns one of these threads to run the `start` method of your operation, and guarantees this thread will never be the main thread.

When the `start` method finishes in a concurrent operation, nothing special happens (which is the point). The queue will allow your operation to run forever until you set `isFinished` to `YES` and do the proper KVO willChange/didChange calls, regardless of the calling thread. Typically you'd make a method called `finish` to do that, which it looks like you have.

All this is fine and well, but there are some caveats involved if you need to observe or manipulate the thread on which your operation is running. The important thing to remember is this: *don't mess with threads managed by GCD*. You can't guarantee they'll live past the current frame of execution, and you definitely can't guarantee that subsequent delegate calls (i.e., from `NSURLConnection`) will occur on the same thread. In fact, they probably won't.

In your code sample, you've shunted `start` off to the main thread so you don't need to worry much about background threads (GCD or otherwise). When you create an `NSURLConnection` it gets scheduled on the current run loop, and all of its delegate methods will get called on that run loop's thread, meaning that starting the connection on the main thread guarantees its delegate callbacks also happen on the main thread. In this sense it's "thread safe" because almost nothing is actually happening on a background thread besides the start of the operation itself, which may actually be an advantage because GCD can immediately reclaim the thread and use it for something else.

Let's imagine what would happen if you didn't force `start` to run on the main thread and just used the thread given to you by GCD. A run loop can potentially hang forever if its thread disappears, such as when it gets reclaimed by GCD into its private pool. There's some techniques floating around for keeping the thread alive (such as adding an empty `NSPort`), but they don't apply to threads created by GCD, only to threads you create yourself and can guarantee the lifetime of.

The danger here is that under light load you actually can get away with running a run loop on a GCD thread and think everything is fine. Once you start running many parallel operations, especially if you need to cancel them midflight, you'll start to see operations that never complete and never deallocate, leaking memory. If you wanted to be completely safe, you'd need to create your own dedicated `NSThread` and keep the run loop going forever.

In the real world, it's much easier to do what you're doing and just run the connection on the main thread. Managing the connection consumes very little CPU and in most cases won't interfere with your UI, so there's very little to gain by running the connection completely in the background. The main thread's run loop is always running and you don't need to mess with it.

It is possible, however, to run an `NSURLConnection` connection entirely in the background using the dedicated thread method described above. For an example, check out [JXHTTP](https://github.com/tumblr/JXHTTP/), in particular the classes [JXOperation](https://github.com/tumblr/JXHTTP/blob/master/JXHTTP/JXHTTPOperation.m) and [JXURLConnectionOperation](https://github.com/tumblr/JXHTTP/blob/master/JXHTTP/JXURLConnectionOperation.m)

Comment: roland, first of all, thank you for your reply. A lot of concepts here. +1 for your support. I have some doubts on the approach of using a concurrent operation together with an async pattern like `NSURLConnection`. What is the advantage of using both if callbacks of `NSURLConnection` are called in the main thread? How can I take advantage of *CDG*? See my edit. Thank you again.

Comment: `NSOperation` is a natural way to encapsulate any long-running, parallelizable task (regardless of the threading advantages). `NSURLConnection` gives you a lot of control via its delegate methods (where to put response data, how to respond to redirection, etc) but they're asynchronous, so if you want to use them inside an `NSOperation` that means it has to be concurrent (otherwise the operation won't live past the exit of its `start` method and continue waiting for delegate callbacks).

Comment: The other main advantage is that it allows you to cancel the connection at any time (for instance, if you were loading an image for a view that the user just dismissed) which is not possible via Cocoa's other connection techniques. You could even override the `cancel` method of `NSOperation` and have it `cancel` the `NSURLConnection` at the same time.

Comment: You don't need to do anything to take advantage of GCD, `NSOperationQueue` manages it for you behind the scenes. In any case, there's not much performance to be gained here anyway. You spend way more time waiting for data over the wire than you do storing it when it arrives. Whatever you wind up doing with the downloaded data is going to be more CPU intensive, and that's the part you should consider doing on a background queue.

Comment: Thank you roland. I see. As I think, delegates are called into the main thread. So, it means that CPU intensive operations need to be done in background (e.g. parsing incoming data). So, my question is: why wrap the `NSURLConnection` into a concurrent `NSOperation` and, then, insert the latter into a queue? Does this lead to any advantages? I cannot see one since callbacks perform operations in main thread. In this manner you cannot take advantage of GCD through `NSOperationQueue`. Hope it is clear. P.S. Yours is a very good answer. Please also think to include your comments into your reply.

Comment: What I mean with *why wrap the NSURLConnection into a concurrent NSOperation and, then, insert the latter into a queue?* is that you could simply have the same effect without `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`. You coud just create your own wrapper. So, **why using `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` if then callbacks are called in the main thread?**

Comment: You're right, there's no reason you can't use `NSURLConnection` directly in a view controller or something like that. Don't get too hung up on the threading aspect of it though, the biggest advantage of `NSOperationQueue` is that you can order the operations and limit how many happen at the same time. For instance, if you needed to download 100 images you'd probably only want to do a few at a time rather than kick off 100 simultaneous connections. In this case your view controller would have an `NSOperationQueue` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to 2 or 4.

Comment: roland, thank you very much for your replies. As already mentioned, please consider to put comments in your reply. Have a nice day.

Comment: Last simple question for you. If I add a concurrent operation to a queue, does the behavior is the same as for non-concurrent operations? In other words, does the queue will create threads for me? As I understand, the queue will manage thread for me, but the operations is not remove until I manage its lifecycle (setting `isFinished` to `YES`). Am I wrong?

Comment: You don't need to do any thread creation, like I said before don't worry about the thread the queue gives you. The only thing you need to worry about is about is setting `isFinished` to `YES` with the KVO willChange/didChange calls (both are important).